# How to avoid that JSON.stringify and JSON.parse replace a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I have been using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to put my rendered html into 1 string, replacing something in that string, and then parsing everything back to the original rendered html format. Like this:

```
res.render('system/error', { title: status.toString(), description: 'This is an error!', nonce: 'nonceValue' }, function(err, html) {
    html = JSON.stringify(html).replace("nonceValue", nonce);
    html = JSON.parse(html);
    res.send(html);
});
```

Does anyone know if there is an easier way to do this?
Can I replace the nonce inside the first html? Without having to `stringify` it?

Comment: What you're doing is a function of template engines, you can use a dedicated template engine such as pugjs etc, here is the list https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html

Comment: i you dont mind, share some example of your JSON data.

Comment: I don't understand. According to the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) the `html` argument is a string. So why would you call `JSON.stringify` on it??

Comment: Use regex?but it's prone to error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, this works:

```
res.render('system/error', { title: status.toString(), description: 'This is an error!', nonce: 'nonceValue' }, function(err, html) {
    html = html.replace("nonceValue", nonce);
    res.send(html);
});
```

I wrote it like because the html object/string was causing issues with Redis and the set.ex() function. But in this usage, it works fine.